# Selenium testing with Jenkins

Tags: linux, selenium, svn, jenkins, automated-tests

I have been trying to start `selenium` tests with browsers, not headless. I have my code in `SVN` and this should be build by `Jenkins`. `Jenkins` is on `Linux`.

Has anyone ever tried that or do you know what steps I should take? I am going through tutorials available on the internet but none of them work for me.

My current error is:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory
>   "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Tests/workspace"): error=2, No such file or
>   directory     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
>     at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:240)  at
>   hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:212)   at
>   hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)   at
>   hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)  at
>   hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:95)
>     at
>   hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:64)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)  at
>   hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory   at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:187)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)  ... 15 more
>   Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

When built without error, the workspace was only updated:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Tests/workspace
Updating http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/resp/extend/Tests/EO at revision '2016-07-04T14:34:05.110 +0200'
At revision 5536

No changes for http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/resp/extend/Tests/EO since the previous build
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If you need any further details, let me know ...

UPDATE:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8771943326851387647.sh
+ ./script.sh
/tmp/hudson8771943326851387647.sh: line 2: ./script.sh: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have changed the windows command to shell command. The shell command is:

```
./script.sh
```

I think that the script inside the file i wrong, but does the error I have now mean that the script is wrong or does it reflect to something else? I do not know hwy we have "permission denied" - I have all the right in jenkins.

And this is my script.sh file content:

```
#!/bin/bash

function run_test {

    echo "=== run Selenium tests in Jenkins ==="
    ssh root@$1 "/src/test/java/mainTest/MainOrderTest start"

}

fi
```

I have no knowledge on shell command and I have not found any command that would run this program.

Comment: To run on jenkins to may need to go for headless testing using  HTMl unit driver or phantom js.

Comment: @AutoMater that's definitely not true. Jenkins can run non-headless browsers just fine if the guest OS is also not running headless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to run windows batch scripts on Linux hence the error.

Two options : 
1. Either convert your build scripts to shell and use "execute shell" to call your shell scripts in jenkins 
2. Add a windows slave which will build your windows batch script

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message. If I have a local project on my pc (windows) and I try to run it in jenkins (linux) - is this the same situation?

Comment: in that case you can configure your pc as a node in jenkins and run the build scripts on the node instead of master.

Comment: thanks! I changed the build step to shell command but the error is the same. in the shell command i refer to `.sh` file - the script itself is probably wrong, but I thought that the error would be slightly different....

Comment: If you truly changed the build step to shell command it would be impossible to get the same error.

Comment: @Mobrockers yes, I got lost between two projects. But after that I changed the windows command to shell and got different error - see update.

Comment: @k.horde your jenkins user has no execute permission on script.sh.

Comment: yes @Mobrockers is correct .. go to linux machine and give execute permission to this script .. use chmod command for this.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot even though it was not the issue here. Stupid, but I did not have maven installed in this linux... Thanks everyone!!!!